# Custom ajax calls in ampersand.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, ampersand.js

I know `model/collection RESTful` stuff. But I need to make custom `ajax` calls in `ampersand.js`, but I can't seem to find the `API` for it. Should I just fall back to using plain old `xmlhttprequest` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the custom call is used to populate a `model/collection`, you should consider using the [`ajaxConfig`](https://github.com/AmpersandJS/ampersand-model#ajaxconfig-modelajaxconfig-or-modelajaxconfig) option.

Otherwise you can just use a module like [`xhr`](https://github.com/Raynos/xhr) that `ampersand-sync` uses itself, to abstract the `xmlhttprequest`, for example:

```
var xhr = require("xhr")

xhr({
  body: someJSONString,
  uri: "/foo",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
}, function (err, resp, body) {
  // check resp.statusCode
})
```